# How was "My Octopus Teacher" filmed? How much of it is a real documentary?

Tags: film-techniques, documentary

The film [My Octopus Teacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Octopus_Teacher) is advertised as a "documentary" film.

But after watching it, a few questions come to mind:

- According to the story, Craig did his one year's adventure with the octopus alone, while filming it. But it is clear that many of the scenes in the film were shot by someone else than Craig (e.g. he is seen underwater from a distance, or filmed from a drone while swimming in the sea). Is it possible that many of the scenes were filmed afterward when someone heard about the story and decided it will be a good idea to turn it into a full feature film? And the scenes were recreated?
- How is it possible that ALL the events involving the Octopus in the film (from minor to major events) happened, how lucky, right in front of the camera, with the best lighting conditions, right at the moments when Craig (who is free-diving) is underwater and precisely at the hours that he is in the Ocean and not elsewhere? Everything is so nicely captured and documented. It just doesn't make sense.

Is it possible that the film is a result of a combination of many *many* different shots, some taken by Craig, other taken later by professional underwater photographers & divers, that gathered all kinds of shots of different octopuses in different locations, spanning several years, and combined them into one fluent film?

Comment: From wikipedia article you linked " Cinematography was directed by underwater cameraman Roger Horrocks with footage from Craig Foster and Roger Horrocks"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whb4unrhy44

Comment: @BCdotWEB, wow that youtube review destroys the documentary.

Answer (score 2):

The making of the movie is explained in [The Making of *My Octopus Teacher*](https://stories.seachangeproject.com/the-making-of-my-octopus-teachernbsp).
The documentary was done by a small group but most of the parts that feature Craig and the octopus were filmed by Craig himself.

Comment: Please add the relevant part from that link to your post. Your answer will become invalid if this link is gone.